# Cancel does not appear on sweetalert 2 on laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert, sweetalert2, laravel-8

I want an alert to pop up if the user wants to submit as approval. However, when clicking submit on sweetalert it only appears ok, there is no cancel option.

How do I get the cancel option to appear?

Here's my blade script:

```
<form action="{{ route('Upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" class="formsubmit">
                                              @csrf
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label for="title">Title:</label>
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title" name="title" >
                                                  <!-- <span class="text-danger error-text judul_err"></span> -->
                                                  @error('title')
                                                    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
                                                        {{ $message }}
                                                    </div>
                                                @enderror
                                              </div>
                                              <!-- <div class="form-group">
                                                        <b>Images</b><br/>
                                                        <input type="file" name="file">
                                                    </div> -->
                                            <div class="custom-file">
                                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input @error('file') is-invalid @enderror" name="file">
                                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Pilih Berkas Maks. 2 MB</label>
                                                @error('file')
                                                    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
                                                        {{ $message }}
                                                    </div>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                          </br>
                                          </br>
                                          </br>
                                            <div align="center">
                                              <input type="submit" value="Autentikasi" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
                                            </div>
                                            </form>
```

And script javascript :

````
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('submit', '[id^=form]', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var data = $(this).serialize();
          swal({
              title: "Are you sure?",
              text: "Do you want to submit and pay 10 Rupiah",
              type: "warning",
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonText: "Yes, send it!",
              cancelButtonText: "No, cancel pls!",
          }).then(function () {
              $('#form').submit();
          });
          return false;
        });
        </script> ```

And the result is like this :
[Cancel does not appear on sweetalert 2 on laravel 8][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmvy1.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using the latest version of Sweet Alert, since you're using the latest Laravel. If this is the case, you need to update your javascript to the more recent SweetAlert methods.

This was tested and works with the latest version of jQuery and SweetAlert.

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- sweetalert -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swal({
            icon: "warning",
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Do you want to submit and pay 10 Rupiah",
            buttons: ["No, cancel pls!", "Yes, send it!"],
        })
        .then((value) => {
            console.log('form submitted');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you the cancel button appears ^^. But, when I want to click the approval, nothing happens (no response data has been successfully submitted). :(